# Создание диапазона C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

смысл идеи такой
есть к примеру диапазон в string "01.01" до "01.02"
на выходе нужно получить IEnumerable
что должно входить в IEnumerable
"01.01",
"02.01",
"03.01",
"04.01",
"05.01",
"06.01",
...
"01.02"

Comment: т.е. диапазон должен быть 01.01, 02.01, ..., 99.01, 01.02?

Comment: вообще максимальное значение должно быть 31,это диапазон для дат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну раз уж через LINQ:

```cs
using static Enumerable;
```

```cs
var dates = Range(1, 12)
    .SelectMany(
        _ => Range(1, 31),
        (mounth, day) => $"{day:D2}.{mounth:D2}");
```

Если вым нужно получить определённое количество дат, то просто используйте `Take`:

```cs
static EnumerateDates() => Range(1, 12)
    .SelectMany(
        _ => Range(1, 31),
        (mounth, day) => $"{day:D2}.{mounth:D2}");
```

```cs
var dates = EnumerateDates().Take(31);
```

Answer (score 4):

Если это действительно даты, то лучше использовать, собственно, даты:

```
var year = 2021;
var startDay = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 365)
    .Select(x => startDay.AddDays(x).ToString("dd.MM"));
foreach (var date in dates)
    Console.WriteLine(date);
```

иначе получите 31 февраля и всё в таком духе

[Пример](https://ideone.com/CXUlmR)

Вместо захардкоженной константы 365, можете использовать метод `DateTime.IsLeapYear` для проверки високосности года.

Если вам больше по душе все же соседний пример, то вместо `Range(1, 31)` можно воспользоваться методом `DateTime.DaysInMonth`

Comment: какого качества вопрос, такого качества и ответ (мой) :)